# How to find string by filter in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have a problem here:
I have an text like this

```
a lot of html tags 
MPI-START
Hello world!
Hello world 2!
MPI-END
a lot of html tags again
```

And somehow I need to get text between MPI-START and MPI-END
It can contains many lines and text so I need to get them all
I tried to search but there are nothing
Any ideas?
Also sorry for my english, i from Russia
UPD: That text what i needed contains in `< p data-placeholder="Your story...">TEXT</ p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found answer
Not perfect but works

```vb
Dim strid, outstr
strid = "many hell tags MPI-START" & vbNewLine & "Hello World!" & vbNewLine & "Hello World 2 !" & vbNewLine & "MPI-END there too"

outstr = Split (strid, "MPI-START")(1)
outstr = Split (outstr, "MPI-END")(0)

MsgBox outstr
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approch using `RegEx` in vbscript to extract data between two delimiters :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Full_String,First_Delimiter,Second_Delimiter,Extracted_Data

Full_String = "a lot of html tags" & vbNewLine &_
"< p data-placeholder=""Your story..."">" & vbNewLine &_
"Hello world!" & vbNewLine &_
"Hello world 2!" & vbNewLine &_
"</ p>" & vbNewLine &_
"a lot of html tags again"

wscript.echo Full_String

First_Delimiter = "< p data-placeholder=""Your story..."">"
Second_Delimiter = "</ p>"
Extracted_Data = ExtractData(Full_String,First_Delimiter,Second_Delimiter)

wscript.echo Extracted_Data

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function ExtractData(Full_String,Start_Delim,End_Delim)
Dim r,Matches,Data
    Set r=new regexp
    r.pattern = "(?:^|(?:\r\n))(:?"& Start_Delim &"\r\n)([\s\S]*?)(?:\r\n)(?:"& End_Delim &")"
    Set Matches = r.Execute(Full_String)
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then Data = Matches(0).SubMatches(1)
    ExtractData = Data
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```